# Take screenshot of a program with visual style

Tags: c#

I'm using this code

```
public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
{
      RECT rc;
      GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
      Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
      IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

      PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);

      gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
      gfxBmp.Dispose();

      return bmp;
 }
```

In order to capture screenshot of a program, it works well but it takes only the basic visual style (please check image below, Left one is the captured by the code above, Right one is captured by `Alt+Prntscr`)

[image: lRr1L.png]

So.. is there anyway to capture screenshot of a program with visual style?

Comment: the two images overlay each other and even then, do not show what you are asking for.

Comment: Wrong pixel format, probably.  Change to Format32bppArgb and try again.

Comment: I figured out myself ... by changing the 3rd parameter in PrintWindow method i can take the screenshot of a program with visual style.
0 -> basic visual style
1 -> only content, no border
2 -> visual style

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links you can try:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.printwindow

What I use is:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
private Bitmap memoryImage;
```

...

```
private void CaptureWindow()
{
    Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    Size s = this.Size;
    memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
    Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
    IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
    IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
    //BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
    BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);
    mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
    memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
}
```

where `memoryImage` is the bitmap to print.